# Extracting only date portion from LastLogonDate

Tags: powershell, automation

I want to be able to isolate the date from the output of this Get-ADUser command:

```
Get-ADUser -identity johnd -properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object name, LastLogonDate
```

Which results in this:

```
name                                                        LastLogonDate
----                                                        -------------
John Doe                                                3/21/2016 10:01:36 AM
```

I want to be able to strip all the text and be left with only the date:

```
3/21/2016
```

I've tried adding this split filter to the end of the above command, which is similar to awk in unix. (#2 is off, just for example)

```
%{ $_.Split(',')[2]; }
```

Which results in this error:

```
[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser] doesn't contain a method named 'Split'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of that cmdlet is an object with a set of properties. The output you see in table format is not what is literally contained in the object; it's a display representation of it.

So to first get the date object only, you can modify your `Select-Object` call (which is already paring down the properties) like this:

```
$lastLogon = Get-ADUser -identity johnd -properties LastLogonDate | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastLogonDate
```

`$lastLogon` now contains a [`[DateTime]` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

With that you can format it using [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$lastLogon.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Or even better:

```
$lastLogon.ToShortDateString()
```

(these are slightly different representations; the latter doesn't zero-pad).

The format strings give you complete control over the representation.

Comment: got me again. Don't do string manipulation when you don't need to is the message here.

Comment: Thank you very much Briantist - that looks to be what I am looking for! I really appreciate you helping!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use variables? If so,

```
PS>$hi=Get-ADuser -identity johnd -properties LastLogonDate|select-object name,LastLogonDate
PS>$hi.LastLogonDate.ToShortDateString()
3/21/2016
PS>$hi.name
John Doe
```

Comment: This seems an awkward way to get this information. Look at briantist's answer for another approach

Comment: Getting the info (a single AD-query for both the name and the LastLogonDate) is better as one command. I agree that my original attempt at constructing the date string was clunky. Giving Briantist a point for the ToShortDateString() method.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple np, easy mistake. This is a good approach too, +1

Answer (score 0):

I'ts hard way, more seamply way is:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=Home,DC=Domain,DC=local' -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -Properties * | 
ForEach-Object {$_.whenChanged.ToShortDateString() + ',' + $_.SamAccountName}
```